# Counting Activities (Open/Closed Tasks and Open/Closed Events) Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'system.now'

Tags: apex, class, error, activities, event

**Issue:**

Below is a part of my class for updating Activity Count fields.  I want to only select the id's from closed Tasks and also closed Events.  I have no clue why my two lists below give me the **"Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'system.now'"**:

List leadsWithClosedTasks = [select id,Lead_Activity_Count_Closed__c,(select id, Status from    Tasks where Status = 'Completed'), (select id, EndDateTime from Events where EndDateTime >= system.now())from Lead where Id IN : Leadids];

List leadsWithClosedTasks = [select id,Lead_Activity_Count_Closed__c,(select id, Status from Tasks where Status = 'Completed'), (select id, EndDateTime from Events where EndDateTime >= system.now())from Lead where Id IN : Leadids];

**What we need:**

We need to select the just the id's of the "Closed" Tasks and ALSO "Closed" Events and also vice versa for Open Tasks and Events.  Selecting Closed & Open Events is not working for some reason?  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you ahead of time.

```
    //update all of the Leads with the number of Closed Tasks and Closed Events
    List<Lead> leadsWithClosedTasks = [select id,Lead_Activity_Count_Closed__c,
   (select id, Status from Tasks where Status = 'Completed'), (select id, EndDateTime 
   from Events where EndDateTime >= system.now())from 

    Lead where Id IN : Leadids];

    List<Lead> leadsUpdatableClosed = new List<Lead>();

    for(Lead Lclosed : leadsWithClosedTasks){

    Lclosed.Lead_Activity_Count_Closed__c = Lclosed.Tasks.size();
    leadsUpdatableClosed.add(Lclosed);

    }

    if(leadsUpdatableClosed.size()>0){
    update leadsUpdatableClosed;
    }


    //update all of the Leads with the number of Open Tasks and Open Events
    List<Lead> leadsWithOpenTasks = [select id,Lead_Activity_Count_Closed__c,
    (select id, Status from Tasks where Status != 'Completed'),(select id, EndDateTime 
    from Events where EndDateTime < system.now()) from 

    Lead where Id IN : Leadids];

    List<Lead> leadsUpdatableOpen = new List<Lead>();

    for(Lead Lopen : leadsWithOpenTasks){

    Lopen.Lead_Activity_Count_Open__c = Lopen.Tasks.size();
    leadsUpdatableOpen.add(Lopen);



    if(leadsUpdatableOpen.size()>0){
    update leadsUpdatableOpen;
    }
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to bind a system function inside a query, so it should be:

```
EndDateTime >= :System.now()
```

You could also use the date literal:

EndDateTime >= TODAY

But this is semantically different (it starts at 12:00:00 AM instead of the current instance in time).